# Redirecionamento depois de deletar registro Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou tendo problemas de redirecionar o usuário depois que o registro é apagado.

Form do botão de delete:

```
        <form action="list/{{$pessoa->id}}" method="POST" >
            @csrf 
            @method('DELETE')
            <button type="submit">
                Delete
            </button>
        </form>
```

Rota para chamar a função destroy:

```
Route::delete('/list/{id}', [PessoaController::class, 'destroy']);
```

Função que deleta o registro no banco:

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $pessoa = Pessoa::findOrFail($id);
    $endereco = Endereco::where('id', $pessoa->endereco_id)->first();
    $estado = Estado::where('id', $endereco->estados_id)->first()->delete();
    $endereco->delete();
    Pessoa::findOrFail($id)->delete();

    return redirect('/list');
}
```

Quando o usuario clica no botão delete ele esta indo para a rota **/list/ID** porém quero que ele vá apenas para o **/list**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava que não utilizar a variável $pessoa quando for deletear.

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $pessoa = Pessoa::findOrFail($id);
    $endereco = Endereco::where('id', $pessoa->endereco_id)->first();
    $estado = Estado::where('id', $endereco->estados_id)->first()->delete();
    $endereco->delete();
    $pessoa->delete();

    return redirect('/list');
}
```